# Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that '(UITextRange) -> String?' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make an electronic circuit calculator which takes values from the text fields and then converts them to Float values before outputting to another text field. I receive this error whether I place inside the if statement or outside. It's the same results whether I use let or var for the ans variable.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var valueVcc: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueBeta: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueR1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueR2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueRc: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueRe: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueVce: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var results: UITextField!
    var Ic = -1 // set initial value for Ic
    //var R1 = Float(valueR1.text)
    // var R2 = Float(valueR2.text)
    // var Vcc = Float(valueVcc.text)
    // var Vb = (Vcc * (R1 / (R1 + R2)))
    @IBAction func buttonR1R2(_ sender: UIButton) {
       var ans = (Float(valueR1.text) / Float(valueR2.text)) // error on this line
        if (!valueR1.text!.isEmpty && !valueR2.text!.isEmpty && !valueVcc.text!.isEmpty) {
            results.text = "Values Entered"
            
        } else {
                results.text = "Enter some values for Vcc,R1 and R2"
        }// end of if statement
        
    }  //end of func buttonR1R2
    
    @IBAction func buttonIcCalc(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to say `ans = (Float(valueR1.text) / Float(valueR2.text))` because either of those `text` values might be `nil` or, if not `nil`, might not be a number. You need to make sure of both those things _first_ before you can perform the division.

Comment: Doesn't the !.isEmpty perform those checks? I have tried using "not nil" and the code gives errors with that. It seems to work fine with .isEmpty.  What's the best way to check to see if the text field not empty and a number? I'm kind of a newbie.

Comment: Well the isEmpty comes later...